# How to append bootstrap-multiselect to div

Tags: jquery, append, electron, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to append HTML code to an HTML file with js. Inside code which is to be addes is a bootstrap-multiselect selector. 
But when i add it, there is no "bootstrap-multiselect" style, it is only bootstrap.
I am programming a dynamical desktop application based with electron.
I know that the code which is appended has to be compressed in one line.

I hope you understand my problem. 
Thank you for your answers.

And sorry for bad english

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

**HTML**

```
<div id="componentsID" class="components">
  <div class="button-class">
        <button id="componentsButton" class="w3-btn w3-green w3-text-white w3-round-large">Add new Component</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#componentsID").on('click', '#componentsButton', function() {
  var component= '<select class="form-control multiselect-class" id="mime-type" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="...">...</option>
        <option value="...">...</option>
  </select>';
$("#componentsID").append(component);
```

Comment: Have you linked .css and .js files from the component in your html file?

Comment: Yes when I dont append such content it is shown correctly.
Only when I do it dynamicaly it isnt shown right